# How to build an SBT app in docker and use it in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, scala, sbt

I've following `docker-compose.yml` file. In JDBC connection string, I'm using the service name I defined but still the application is failing to resolve the hostname.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
    clear_api:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        restart: "always"
        depends_on:
            - clear_mysql
            - clear_redis
        links:
            - clear_mysql
            - clear_redis
    clear_mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        volumes:
            - ./docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./scripts/initialize.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    clear_redis:
        image: "redis"
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 6379:6379
        volumes:
            - ./docker/redis_local:/data
```

The connection string I'm using

`"jdbc:mysql://clear_mysql/cleardb?useSSL=false"`

Error:

```
#0 120.9 [error] Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
#0 120.9 [error] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
#0 120.9 [error]        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
#0 120.9 [error]        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
#0 120.9 [error]        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
#0 120.9 [error]        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
#0 120.9 [error]        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
#0 120.9 [error]        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
#0 120.9 [error]        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
#0 120.9 [error]        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
#0 120.9 [error]        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
#0 120.9 [error]        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
#0 120.9 [error]        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120)
#0 121.0 [error]        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:944)
#0 121.0 [error]        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:814)
#0 121.0 [error]        ... 14 more
#0 121.0 [error] Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: clear_mysql: Name does not resolve
#0 121.0 [error]        at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
#0 121.0 [error]        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:932)
```

The docker-compose.yml file seems good to me but still it's failing with service host name resolution. Any suggestions for the solution or any mistake?

UPDATE:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM oarkflow/clear-sbt as api
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl ca-certificates unzip coreutils bash
WORKDIR /api
COPY ./clear-api .
RUN sbt publishLocal

FROM oarkflow/clear-sbt as service
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl ca-certificates unzip coreutils bash
WORKDIR /service
COPY ./clear-service .
COPY --from=api /root/.ivy2/local/com.example/root/.ivy2/localcom.example
RUN sbt "runMain clear.service.Local"
```

Comment: To double-check, you're getting this error out of the container proper (`docker-compose logs clear_api`); you're not trying to connect to this database from a host development environment or in your Dockerfile?

Comment: From Dockerfile, the application is being built and it's trying to connect to database.

Comment: You need really to be able to ping host clear_mysql from the client

Comment: Since the api is failing on build, mysql is not available. failing api is stopping mysql

Comment: A Dockerfile can't connect to other containers at all.  Why do you need to connect to the database as part of your image build?  (What should happen if you build the image, then delete and recreate the database?)

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong in code. In Dockerfile, I'm trying to build image for the application and the command I used to run is `sbt "runMain clear.service.Local"`. I think this command is required to compile scala app. But at the same point it's connecting to database. Not sure for appropriate solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're running a command to run your API/service during the container build:

```
RUN sbt "runMain clear.service.Local"
```

This will try to compile and run the application as part of the container build

You want to run only a packaging phase as part of the container build.
Depending on your project and plugins, this command could be `sbt dist` or `sbt stage` for example.

This command should generate a bunch of JAR and maybe a shell script that you can use as a `CMD` directive in your dockerfile so that it gets executed when the container is started (as opposed to when it's being built).

You migt want to check out "universal packaging" at https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#build. (There's also a docker packaging that could generate the Dockerfile for you but that's another approach).